# "Le" in French family names

Tags: étymologie, articles, noms-de-famille

What is the origin of (p)article *"le"* in some of French family names (*Lelaure, Lelandais, Leclerc*)?

As far as I understand, *"de"* in family names usually originates from the name of a territory owned by a noble family (*de Gaulle, Defay, de Ligonnès*), arising from a genitive construction (*X de Y*), meaning that the person came from this territory or owns it - as we would say "Elisabeth of England" or "Nicholas of Russia". Does *"le"* have similar origin? What does it mean exactly then?

A related question: is it true that joint or separate spelling is characteristic of specific geographic regions (like *de Fay* vs. *Defay*)?

Comment: Related https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41231/prononciation-du-nom-de-famille-lebesgue/41232#41232

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Family names haven't always existed. They began to be fixed during the Middle-Ages. Before people were designated in accordance to a moral trait (*Le Petit, Le Gentil, Le Doux* ...) a physical characteristic (*Le Brun, Le Noir, Le Gros* ...), their trade (*Le Charpentier, Le Boulanger, Le Clerc* ...), or their place of dwelling or birth origin (*Le Landais, Le Bois/Du Dois, L'Anglais, Le Breton* ...).

Family names originate from this way of naming people and *le* here is just the definite article attached to the noun. The fact that *le* is attached to the noun is not specific to a family name having a geographical origin.

*Le bon usage* mentions this (§236, 10th edition). A more detailed article can be found on [*Ça m'intéresse*](https://www.caminteresse.fr/societe/dou-viennent-nos-noms-de-famille-133020/).

For anyone who is interested in a historic approach I've found this academic paper *Le patronyme : Histoire, anthropologie, société* <sup>1</sup>, it goes far beyond the question. Here's an extract related to the question:

> Les formes utilisant articles et prépositions disparaissent progressivement : en 1340, elles concernent 60 % de mentions, 50 % en 1410, 10 % en 1470. Le surnom reste longtemps soumis aux règles grammaticales du « nom commun », signalant quelqu’un de tel lieu, exerçant tel métier, affublé de telle caractéristique morale ou physique ; c’est seulement à la fin du Moyen Âge qu’il s’en émancipe et devient « nom propre ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> ZEI, Gianna (dir.) ; DARLU, Pierre (dir.) ; et BRUNET, Guy (dir.). *Le patronyme : Histoire, anthropologie, société*. Nouvelle édition [en ligne]. Paris : CNRS Éditions, 2001.</sup>

Comment: I guess here that for the majority of peasants that have no lands, using such last name was a necessity.